# Button removal in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to nest pages and such with button presses in an app I am working on. However, as  a widget, it carries over and such and must be removed using display.remove() or :removeSelf. I'm trying to make these buttons delete/remove themselves from the view as they are pressed and the next page is loaded, but when I do this it either does not work, or throws a runtime error. Suggestions?

Edit: This is what I am currently using, although it leaves the button gone permanently after click.
`

```
local onButtonEvent = function (event )
    if event.phase == "release" then
        display.remove( myButton )
        myButton = nil
        display.remove( buttonGroup )
        buttonGroup = nil
        storyboard.gotoScene( "shape" )
    end
end
```

Comment: Why don't you share some code?

Comment: Alright, I added what I am currently using, although its a workaround at the moment.

Comment: OK! Code looks good.  What Runtime error are you getting?  And what do you mean "although it leaves the button gone permanently after click."
I though that was the intention - to remove the button on click.

Comment: This version of the code throws no error, but I would like to not remove the group upon leaving (although it seems unavoidable). When you navigate back to the view, the button isn't reloaded this way, thus you initially are able to nest pages like this, but you cannot continue to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way. Why don't you set

```
myButton.isVisible = false
```

inside your onButtonEvent function.

And I've never used StoryBoard, but I'm pretty sure there is a event fired ("willEnterScene" I think) when you enter the scene.

So you can set `mybutton.isVisible = true` there

Answer (score 2):

this will work in lua/ Corona:

```
    MyButton:removeSelf( )
```

removes it completely.

Hope that helps !