# How do I set the visibility of a widget to false?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So, I have this function:

```
local function addMainMenu()
    local widget = require( "widget" )

    -- Function to handle button events
    local function handleButtonEvent( event )

        if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
            scene = "GAME"
        end
    end

    -- Create the widget
    local button1 = widget.newButton(
        {
            label = "button",
            onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
            emboss = false,
            -- Properties for a rounded rectangle button
            shape = "roundedRect",
            width = 200,
            height = 40,
            cornerRadius = 2,
            fillColor = { default={0.9,0.9,0.9,1}, over={1,0.1,0.7,0.4} },
            strokeColor = { default={0,0,0,1}, over={0.8,0.8,1,1} },
            strokeWidth = 5
        }
    )

    -- Center the button
    button1.x = display.contentCenterX
    button1.y = display.contentCenterY

    -- Change the button's label text
    button1:setLabel( "Start Game" )
end
```

That adds the button to start the game, and then I have:

```
local function enterFrame()
    local dt = getDeltaTime()
    if (scene == "MAIN_MENU") then
         addMainMenu()
    elseif (scene == "GAME") then
        if (running == false) then
            startGame()
        else 
            moveBg(dt)
            moveEnemy(enemy)
            updateScore()
        end
    elseif (scene == "GAME_OVER") then
        local gameOverLabel = display.newText( "Game Over!", 50, 20, native.systemFont, 16)
        gameOverLabel:setFillColor(1, 1, 1)
    end
end
```

As you can see, once I click on the button to start, the scene changes to "GAME", and the button should go away. The thing is: It stays there. [And reading the docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html), I can't find a way to set its visibility to false. How can I cease displaying a widget?

Comment: the answer is in the manual or can be found by simply entering "hide button corona" into google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button removal in Corona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883570/button-removal-in-corona)

Answer (score 2):

To make it not visible use .isVisible:

```
button1.isVisible = false
```

To hide it use .alpha

```
button1.alpha = 0.00
-- or hide just a little by 50%
button1.alpha = 0.50
```

To remove it:

```
display.remove( button1)
button1= nil
```

Answer (score 1):

A [ButtoWidget](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ButtonWidget/index.html) inherits from [GroupObject](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/GroupObject/index.html) which inherits from [DisplayObject](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/index.html) which provides the property [isVisible](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/isVisible.html)

> **Overview**
>
> Controls whether the object is visible on the screen. The
>   property is also readable. The default is true.
>
> **Example**
>
> `local rect1 = display.newRect( 100, 100, 50, 50 )`
>
> `rect1:setFillColor( 0.7 )`
>
> `local rect2 = display.newRect( 150, 100, 50, 50 )`
>
> `rect2:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0, 0.6 )`
>
> `rect2.isVisible = false`

`button1.isVisible = false` will hide the button. It will disappear with the next screen update.

In case you don't need the button anymore you can as well just remove it by calling `button1:removeSelf()` or by removing it from it's parent group